Modify UI via a lot of other threads than the main thread
I am developing a program that downloads comics from a website. The program has a search engine that allows users to search. Each time a letter is typed, a GET request is sent to the site, and the names and covers of the first two comics in the search results are retrieved. This part works smoothly.
However, since adding the comic covers to the interface takes a long time, I wanted to perform this operation on a separate thread. But there is a conflict between threads, and the program crashes when typing too quickly in the search box.
I tried keeping active threads in a dictionary and ensuring that if a new thread starts while an active thread exists, the active thread would be terminated before starting the new thread, but it didn't work.

from sys import exit, argv
from os import listdir, path
from importlib import util
from mylib.PySide2.helpers import clear_layout
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QComboBox, QLineEdit, QGraphicsDropShadowEffect, QFrame
from PySide2.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter, QColor, QFont, QPalette
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QByteArray, QThread, Signal, QTimer

import requests
from urllib.parse import urlencode


def get_response(query: str, per_page: int) -> dict:
    response = requests.get(f"https://mangagalaxy.org/api/query?searchTerm={query}&perPage={per_page}")
    return response.json()


def get_datas(json: dict) -> list[tuple[str, str]]:
    data = []
    for i in json["posts"]:
        data.append((
            i["postTitle"],
            convert_url(i["featuredImage"])
        ))
    return data


def convert_url(original_url):
    new_params = {
        'url': original_url,
        'w': 128,
        'q': 30
    }

    encoded_params = urlencode(new_params)

    new_url = f"https://mangagalaxy.org/_next/image?{encoded_params}"

    return new_url


def search(query: str, per_page: int) -> list[tuple[str, str]]:
    return get_datas(get_response(query=query, per_page=per_page))


class ImageLoad(QThread):
    success = Signal(QPixmap)

    def __init__(self, parent, url, label):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.url = url
        self.label = label

    def run(self):
        try:
            image_data = requests.get(self.url).content
            if image_data:
                pixmap = QPixmap(128, 180)
                data = QByteArray(image_data)
                if pixmap.loadFromData(data):
                    self.success.emit(pixmap)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)


class ResultWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, title=None, image=None, no=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.no = no
        self.parent = parent
        layout = QHBoxLayout()

        self.photo_label = QLabel()
        self.load_photo(image)
        layout.addWidget(self.photo_label)

        title_label = QLabel(title)
        layout.addWidget(title_label)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def load_photo(self, url):
        self.photo_label.setPixmap(loading_pixmap)
        self.photo_label.setFixedSize(loading_pixmap.size())
        def finished():
            self.parent.active_threads[self.no] = None

        self.worker = ImageLoad(self, url, self.photo_label)
        self.worker.success.connect(lambda pixmap: self.photo_label.setPixmap(pixmap))
        self.parent.active_threads[self.no] = self.worker
        self.worker.start()
        self.worker.finished.connect(finished)




class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.active_threads = {}
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        # ########################################### Main layout
        self.search_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        # ############################ Search layout

        self.search_box = QLineEdit()
        self.search_box.setPlaceholderText("Search")
        self.search_box.textChanged.connect(self.search)
        self.search_layout.addWidget(self.search_box)


        self.results_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.results_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        # ############ Result layout

        self.search_layout.addLayout(self.results_layout)
        # ############ Result layout end


        main_layout.addLayout(self.search_layout)

        # ########################################### Main layout end
        self.main_widget = QWidget()
        self.main_widget.setLayout(main_layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)


    def search(self, event):
        result = search(event, 2)
        self.set_results(result)

    def set_results(self, result):
        clear_layout(self.results_layout)
        for no, i in enumerate(result):
            def a():
                r = ResultWidget(self, i[0], i[1], no)
                self.results_layout.addWidget(r)
            if no in self.active_threads and self.active_threads[no]:
                print("Stopping")
                self.active_threads[no].terminate()
                print("Stopped")
                self.active_threads[no] = None
            a()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(argv)

    loading_pixmap = QPixmap("image.png")

    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    exit(app.exec_())

I even made such an addition, but it still didn't work.
def set_results(self, result):
    clear_layout(self.results_layout)
    for no, i in enumerate(result):
        def a():
            r = ResultWidget(self, i[0], i[1], no)
            self.results_layout.addWidget(r)
        if no in self.active_threads and self.active_threads[no]:
            print("Stopping")
            self.active_threads[no].terminate()
            print("Stopped")
            self.active_threads[no] = None
            timer = QTimer()
            timer.setInterval(1000)
            timer.timeout.connect(a)
            timer.start()

        else:
            a()

In the end, I reluctantly tried something like this, but even with this, there are occasional issues. What method should I use to resolve the problem?
self.search_box.textChanged.connect(self.on_text_changed)

self.timer = QTimer(self)
self.timer.setSingleShot(True)
self.timer.timeout.connect(self.search)

def on_text_changed(self):
    self.timer.start(1000)


The program probably crashes because when the running thread ends it tries to access an instance of ResultWidget or its children, which has been destroyed in the meantime (probably done within clear_layout()), and trying to access a destroyed C++ object always leads to a fatal exception. You may try to use a more appropriate connection: self.worker.success.connect(self.photo_label.setPixmap) (using the lambda in that context is pointless), but reality is that the whole implementation is a bit faulty and not completely reliable. For starters, QPixmap is not considered thread safe and »

» should also always be created in the thread of the QApplication (on some systems that may just not work at all), and QImage should be used instead. Then, as the documentation explains, terminate() is highly discouraged as it's unreliable and dangerous. MainWindow.search() is also inappropriate, since search() is based on get_response(), which is blocking, and that should never happen. Unfortunately, providing an appropriate answer is difficult, as addressing those many issues would mean to rewrite a great portion of your code, and it »

» would still be not very effective unless it was rewritten almost from scratch. I suggest you to reconsider the whole implementation considering the above aspects, including the fact that clearing/recreating widgets (and their own threads) at every text change is not appropriate; at the very least, you should create a persistent timer that eventually makes the query on its timeout and start it when the text is changed, possibly reusing existing widgets instead of deleting and recreating them. Note that you should also consider using QNetworkAccessManager, which is natively asynchronous.

Thank you for all the advice. I will take these into account and rewrite the code.
